# How to filter a data frame in R columns using "OR"?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to filter a data frame with several columns which column x = a or column y = a. How can I do this? I know that to filter only within a column, I can do this:

```
data[data$col1==515, ]
```

Comment: use `|`     as in `data[, data$col==515 | data$col2 == 222]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the logical operator `|` (*or*):

```
data[data$col1 == 515 | data$col2 == 515, ]
```

Another approach is:

```
data[as.logical(rowSums(dat[c("col1", "col2")] == 515)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your questions has a typo in that you're choosing rows instead of columns.

This is what you need.

```
data[ ,sapply(data, function(x) 515 == x)]
```

This will get rid of the columns that are not equal in the data frame to 515.  What's the point of doing this? I don't know. You'll basically end up with a bunch of repeated values 515... So comment and I'll give you a better solution in case I didn't understand the question